# Eloquent | Using with() resulting in NULL bring returned

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to use Eloquent in Laravel in order to run a query. I am using the `with()` function in order to get the results from relationships, however this is always returning `null`.

This is my code:

```
Posts::query()
    ->select('id')
    ->with([
        'author:id',
        'category.images:url',
     ]);
```

Dumping the query using the `getQueryLog()` function and if I run the query inside of a SQL client with the same bindings I get a result back, however the response looks like this...

```
{
    id: 1,
    category: {
       id: 1,
       category_images: null
    }
}
```

I've tried googling this issue and can't really find anything on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try 'category.category_images',

Comment: What do you mean by this line `'category.id:category_images.url',`?

Comment: Sorry I mistyped that, edited the code now. I'm trying to reference the category relationship with images as a relationship on that and just select the url.

Comment: try it like this `'category.images:id,url',` because in the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) it's said that : `When using this feature, you should always include the id column in the list of columns you wish to retrieve.`

Comment: you should still select the column that relates `image` to `category` in the eager load, so eloquent can match the children to their parents .. perhaps `category_id` (don't know how you named the keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your query like this:

```
Posts::query()->select('id')->with([ 'author', 'category' ])->get();
```

and in Posts model

```
public function author()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('Authors::class', 'author_id', 'id')->select('id');
}



public function category()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('Categories::class', 'category_id', 'id')->select('id', 'images.id', 'images.url');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to select your foreign keys in select statement to let Eloquent query your relationships, something like this:

```
Posts::query()
    ->select('id', 'author_id', 'category_id')
    ->with([
        'author:id',
        'category.images:url',
    ]);
```